# c++ use new to Image gdi+

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, winapi, gdi+

im using gdi+ to output my images.
i tried to use the keyword new but it didn't work.

```
shot(L"image name") = new Image;
```

that didn't work any other ideas how to make it work

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"? Presumably you mean "didn't compile" - what error did the compiler give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems a lot more likely:

```
Image *image_object = new Image(L"Image Name");
```

Except that there's a pretty decent chance you don't want to allocate the Image object dynamically at all -- unless you really do, you generally want to just define an object with automatic storage duration:

```
Image image_object(L"Image Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

The GDI+ Image class is not default constructible. You have to supply some parameters to the constructor in order to create one - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#constructors).

You may well be better off using `Gdiplus::Bitmap`, which derives from Image. That seems more likely if you're trying to output it.